# Getting to the next page using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to make a web scraper but I'm unable to get the link of the next page. I have tried some combinations but none of them work. The tutorial on scrapy.org has a simpler format so it doesn't solve my problem

The site I'm scraping has the following layout:

```
<nav class="nav_class">
    <a class="class_1" href="1.html">
    <a class="class_2" href="2.html">
    <a class="class_3" href="3.html">
```

I want to get the 3.html link using css selectors

```
import scrapy


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "flip_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            "https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&p%5B%5D=facets.processor_brand%255B%255D%3DSnapdragon&p%5B%5D=facets.serviceability%5B%5D%3Dfalse&p%5B%5D=facets.offer_type%255B%255D%3DExchange%2BOffer&otracker=clp_banner_1_10.bannerX3.BANNER_mobile-phones-store_HPUGCU9BYBF6&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_934db066-154e-4074-a4b1-96f56a0af28e_6.HPUGCU9BYBF6&ppt=HomePage&ppn=Home&ssid=85m4yqvgzk0000001558978084715&page=1",
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # page_id=response.url.split("=")[-1]
        phone_details = response.css("div._1-2Iqu.row")

        for ph in phone_details:
            phone = ph.css("div._3wU53n::text").get()
            rating = ph.css("div.hGSR34::text").get()
            price = ph.css("div._1vC4OE._2rQ-NK::text").get()

            yield{
                "name": phone,
                "rating": rating,
                "price": price,
            }
        final = "https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&p%5B%5D=facets.processor_brand%255B%255D%3DSnapdragon&p%5B%5D=facets.serviceability%5B%5D%3Dfalse&p%5B%5D=facets.offer_type%255B%255D%3DExchange%2BOffer&otracker=clp_banner_1_10.bannerX3.BANNER_mobile-phones-store_HPUGCU9BYBF6&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_934db066-154e-4074-a4b1-96f56a0af28e_6.HPUGCU9BYBF6&ppt=HomePage&ppn=Home&ssid=85m4yqvgzk0000001558978084715&page=6"
        next_page_id = response.css("nav._1ypTlJ a._3fVaIS::attr(href)").get()

        # ^This is the line I need help with

        if next_page_id is not final:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page_id)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

It only scrapes the first page and then stops

Comment: Are you sure those classes exist in the HTML code? Try downloading the page into a local file and opening it with a text editor, and try to find those HTML classes (e.g. `_1ypTlJ`). Also, consider using `scrapy shell` to test your XPath expressions first, the issue can be probably reproduces with it as well, and it would have made your question code much shorter.

Comment: I inspected the site to find out these classes. I did the same to find out the div classes as well and the code works fine there. I'll still try downloading it to get a better look. Thanks!

Comment: Mind that web browser inspectors don’t show the HTML structure. It’s the DOM, which not always (and often does not) represent the actual underlying HTML. It almost always includes extra HTML elements (e.g. `<tbody>` within tables) and is often modified by JavaScript code. In fact, random-looking HTML class names like those in your code are likely to have been automatically generated from JavaScript.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to this and it will work

```
next_page_id = response.css("nav._1ypTlJ a._3fVaIS::attr(href)").get()

if next_page_id:
    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page_id)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```